# Mount ceiling fan at the peak of a sloped ceiling

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I'm hoping to replace a hanging pendant light with a ceiling fan at peak of vaulted ceiling. Issue is how/where to get a junction box up there. Current situation (whatever that is), obviously, will not support a fan.

Looking for ideas. Rather not move it to one side or the other of the slope from the peak. Could drop it down a few inches and frame something around the box but that might be an odd looking detail.

Anyone encountered this condition before?

[image]

[image]

Comment: what  are your DIY skills on 1-10 scale

Comment: 1-10…I'm probably a soft 7

Comment: Soft 7 means you have done this before at least once

Answer (score 4):

Get out your drywall repair tools and a stud finder! One hopes those visible bare timbers are structural -- they look like an appealing place to drop a couple planks to provide a comfortable work platform. When it's all said and done you will have spent a few hours up there cutting drywall, adding framing, repairing drywall, and painting.

The usual solution is to build a little box at the peak so that there's a flat, level area from which the fan can hang. There are many ways to do it; you'll have to find out what structure is already present behind the drywall and apply some creativity. A web search for "vaulted ceiling fan mount" will yield many ideas. A common choice is to build it with dimensional lumber and wrap with drywall. You might instead choose to build it with plywood, a solid wood like oak or maple or alder, or even rough-hewn timber to match those rafter ties and leave the wood showing. Here are a few I found, both from Pinterest:

[image]
[image]

Arlington Industries makes a line of fan mounts for cathedral/vaulted ceilings. It seems to be offered with several different mounting hardware styles. (photo: crescentelectric.com)

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks!! This Arlington mount looks perfect!! Now to find it… 

Answer (score 2):

You've got a good size light up so there's support and switched power so that's a plus. You are going to have to get up there and cut away a portion of the ceiling the size of a ceiling fan box centered at the peak and see what you've got up there. I'm betting there is some framing up there that will support a fan. It could be a rafter or a cross piece on a rafter. You won't know this until you get up there. How you mount the box will depend on what's up there. Once the box is mounted, You can get a fan that has a deeper canopy that will fit up into the opening after you've cut off more drywall to match the diameter of the canopy.

You've picked the worse place to hang a ceiling fan and working from a ladder at that height presents problems of it's own but I've done this. It's one of those jobs where you don't really know the solution until you've passed the point of no return.